# Calling Powershell commands in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, powershell

I have this powershell script and I have manually executed this

```
powershell -command "C:\shellcommand.ps1"
```

Could you please help me how i can able to call this in python

Comment: Please do some research. Questions about starting PowerShell scripts from Python have been asked before.

Comment: I have written the powershell commands in python script and saved it as .ps1 file